# VuePress/Vue: Plugins not used during build using a GitLab CI

Tags: vue.js, gitlab-ci, vuepress

I'm looking to deploy a VuePress site using a Gitlab CI pipeline. I use some plugins via the method Vue.use().

When I build manually on my machine and deploy to firebase it works fine. 
When the pipeline is triggered, it passes without issue, however, in the built files there is no trace of the plugins. In the case of Buefy, no Buefy component is generated in the built files.

Here's my EnhanceApp.js file:

```js
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css'

export default ({
    Vue,
    options,
    router,
    siteData
}) => {
    Vue.use(Buefy)
}
```

And here's my .gitlab-cy.yaml

```
image: node:10

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - npm install -g firebase-tools
    - npm i
    - npm run build
    - firebase deploy -m "Pipeline $CI_PIPELINE_ID, build $CI_BUILD_ID" --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

I tried both Firebase and AppEngine to no avail, as well as multiple docker images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GitLab or firebase, but I suggest that you can try to **use Yarn instead of npm**. Because currently npm will cause some problems in Vuepress (e.g. make plugin-google-analytics unavailable).